# React - How to remove image when the max width (mobile version)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I wouldike to remove or hide an image when I run the application in mobile version or if max-width is set :

```
<ImageWrapper key={image.src}>
          <img src={getImageUrl(path, image.src)} srcSet={getSrcSet(path, image.src)} alt={image.alt} />
        </ImageWrapper>
```

Comment: You can use `CSS` to write media query to hide the element on specified width

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try these two steps:

1. in your js file add `className` to your component as follow:

```
<ImageWrapper key={image.src} className="YourClass">
          <img src={getImageUrl(path, image.src)} srcSet={getSrcSet(path, image.src)} alt={image.alt} />
        </ImageWrapper>
```

2. Then, set `display` parameter based on screen size in your CSS file:

```
.YourClass {
  display:block;
  /* other properties */
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .YourClass {
      display:none;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the width of the content in javascript if you like to do this in javascript for some reason.

- **cons**: you have to populate your code with aditional javascript
- **pro**: if the user is using only mobile, it will not request the image which is good to prevent aditional requests. If you use css `display:none` it will request the image anyway.

```js
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

//
const [width, setWidth] = useState(window.innerWidth);

// method to update the width size
const handleWindowSizeChange = () => {
  setWidth(window.innerWidth);
};

// create a eventListener to update the width every time the user resize the window
useEffect(() => {
  handleWindowSizeChange();
  window.addEventListener('resize', handleWindowSizeChange);
  return () => {
    window.removeEventListener('resize', handleWindowSizeChange);
  };
}, []);
```

Now you can use the `width` to check the size and check if the size is mobile or not.

`if(width < 700) { // isMobile }`

TIP: Hide the image in the render:

`{width < 700 && <img src="image.jpg" />}`